# Magento : updating cart total after remove product via API

Tags: api, magento, soap, shopping-cart, subtotal

I am trying to remove item/product from shopping cart in magento by using shoppingCartProductRemove API . The Api works fine and removes the product from cart. But it does not update the cart total after removing the product from cart.

How do I update and recalculate the cart total?

Thanks

```
 try{
        $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductRemove($sessionID, $cartID, array(array(
        'product_id' => $productID,
        'sku' => $sku ,
        'qty' => $qty ,
        'options' => null,
        'bundle_option' => null,
        'bundle_option_qty' => null,
        'links' => null
        )));    


        // update ---------

        $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductUpdate($sessionID, $cartID , array(array(
        'product_id' => $productID,
        'sku' => $sku,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'options' => null,
        'bundle_option' => null,
        'bundle_option_qty' => null,
        'links' => null 

        )));
```

Comment: After removing product using `shoppingCartProductRemove`, are you updating the cart using `shoppingCartProductUpdate` ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy no , after you say i test it but it return to me this message : "Call to a member function getId() on a non-object"

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy i add code that i use to remove and update

Answer (score 0):

While it does not update any values that you have already fetched, if you issue `cart.totals` (SOAP v1) or `shoppingCartTotals()` (SOAP v2) call it should return updated totals for your shopping cart.

More info: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.totals.html

Comment: i am trying with this method "shoppingCartInfo" http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html

Comment: i try shoppingCartTotals() and it`s have same problam

Comment: @Win8_learner i could not find any solution for this problem yet.